# Identical question posted here and on Cross-Validated

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close, cross-posting, cross-validated

The question [Simple Neural Network Implementation in Keras](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27922/simple-neural-network-implementation-in-keras) has been cross-posted here and on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329114/error-in-simple-neural-network-implementation-using-keras/).

I flagged it as a cross-post: it's never ok to cross-post on both sites, see
[When is it okay to cross-post to on Data Science from Cross Validated?](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/when-is-it-okay-to-cross-post-to-on-data-science-from-cross-validated)

Comment: Related: [When is it okay to cross-post to on Data Science from Cross Validated?](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/37/8560), [What should we do when a question posted on DataScience is a duplicate of a question posted on CrossValidated?](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2258/8560)

Comment: There is way too much overlap between DS and Cross Validated... Most questions on DS are very much on-topic on Cross Validated, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good catch.

What should you do in these kinds of situations?  Leave a comment on both posts indicating that it was a cross-post and informing the poster about the "no cross-posting" policy.  Then, decide which site you think it is best-suited on, and flag the copy on the other site to be closed (flag for moderator attention, with a custom flag, and explain your reasons in the textbox).

Here is some stock language you can use for the comment:

`Also posted on Panda Stack Exchange: http://panda.stackexchange.com/q/1.
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.`

> Also posted on Panda Stack Exchange: http://panda.stackexchange.com/q/1.
>   Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

If it's two different people asking two similar questions, this doesn't apply.  You can write an answer summarizing the main idea and linking to the other site, if you want, or just leave a comment with a link to the other question on the other site.

Comment: "If it's two different people asking two similar questions, this doesn't apply. " ->  Why would the rule be different?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this to Meta.

In case of Cross Posts that I run across, I like to leave a comment for the OP explaining that cross-posting is heavily discouraged.  They often just don't know the policy.

In these cases I sometimes flag the post immediately, but I often just star the post, and wait a day or so, to see if the OP can work it out themselves. In most cases they do, and often express their gratitude on having it explained to them how things generally work. If they don't work it out, then I will raise a flag.

So I would highly encourage you, if you have time, to leave a comment on the crosspost explaining the policy, to help [teach the OP to fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime). But in either case it is OK to raise a moderator flag, since the moderators are here to handle the odd situation such as these.

---

I would like to discuss one specific point from your post...

> I flagged it as a cross-post: it's never ok to cross-post on both sites, see [When is it okay to cross-post to on Data Science from Cross Validated?](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/51/29575)

While Cross posting is heavily discouraged, it is not absolutely forbidden. Even in your linked answer, (from [ChrisF](https://stackexchange.com/users/23619/chrisf?tab=accounts), who is a moderator on multiple sites,) you will note that there can be exceptions that prove the rules. Additionally,  ChrisF starts his post with: *"Cross posting is a bad idea. It's rare that exactly the same question is on topic on both sites"*. Both Bad Idea and Rare imply to me that the practice is not absolutely forbidden.

Another [relevant quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates/4713#4713), this time from the Director of Community Development [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino):

> In the edge case where the question is appropriate on more than one site, leave it on both sites and let the users of each community benefit from the information.

I am not condoning cross-posting, just trying to note that there is no absolute here.

Comment: No. Both @ChrisF and Spacedman's answers condemn cross-posting. ChrisF specifically says that "Stack Exchange is all about having one place where people can find the answer to their question. At the very least you should be tailoring your question to each site, emphasising the parts that are particularly relevant for that site over the rest of the question." This isn't what the OP has done: s/he posted the **same identical question** on both sites. This is absolutely not ok.  Spacedman is even more drastic: "I don't really see any reason to cross post (ie to both). "

Comment: Concerning the explanatory comment, you're right, the user has low rep so probably little experience about the rules of the SE network. It's difficult for me now to include links in my comments, but when I'm back to my laptop I'll do that.

Comment: @DeltaIV, absolutely agree.  Not trying to encourage cross posting in anyway. Also not trying to condone the particular crosspost in question. I am simply stating that the rule it is not absolute. ChrisF starts his post with: *"Cross posting is a bad idea. It's **rare** that exactly the same question is on topic on both sites"*.  Both *Bad Idea* and *Rare* imply to me NOT ABSOLUTELY forbidden.  This was the only point I was trying to make.  Sorry if I somehow offended.

Comment: you didn't offend me: I just disagree with you, but I took no offense, and surely meant no offense. Concerning the nuance, you may be right: I weighted more the following sentence, where @ChrisF says that "Stack Exchange is **all** about having **one** place where people can find the answer to their question", but maybe his position is more nuanced than I thought. Anyway, my post was about this specific cross-post: we both agree that this is not one of  the "good" cross-posts, and this is the main thing ;-)