# Custom flag for cross-posting was declined with puzzling justification

Tags: discussion, specific-question, flagging, cross-posting

I recently raised a custom flag in [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/90671/problem-with-gradient-check-tfnp) for being cross-posted to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66635334/tensorflow-numpy-gradient-check-doesnt-work); to my surprize, the flag was

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Apart from the [canonical MSO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) for not allowing cross-posting, here at DSSE, in contrast with several other SE sites, we explicitly request not to cross post in our [on topic](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page (emphasis in the original):

> *Don't post your questions on more than one site.*

Unsurprisingly, the issue of cross-posting has been raised here at Meta a couple of times, and always the advice included to flag it for moderator attention; quoting from [When is it okay to cross-post to on Data Science from Cross Validated?](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/51/43000):

> flag it for moderator attention

Quoting from [What should we do when a question posted on DataScience is a duplicate of a question posted on CrossValidated?](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/what-should-we-do-when-a-question-posted-on-datascience-is-a-duplicate-of-a-ques/2269#2269):

> flag for moderator attention, with a custom flag, and explain your reasons in the textbox

The last advice is repeated verbatim in [Identical question posted here and on Cross-Validated](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2362/43000), where moreover, a site moderator weighs in, and [advises](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2359/43000):

> it is OK to raise a moderator flag, since the moderators are here to handle the odd situation such as these.

Last but not least, a quick look at my flag history reveals that so far I have raised no less than **thirty (30)** similar custom flags for cross-posting, without a single one being ever declined for any reason.

Given the above, why my flag was declined?

In principle, I could understand a reason that I did not include an argument in the textbox regarding at which site the question is off-topic; but an advice for *using standard flags* instead is totally puzzling here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-flagged the question with an identical reasoning, and this time it was indeed deleted, so the rejection of the first flag was probably a moderator mistake (although arguably it should have been taken care of after this post without me needing to re-flag it, since there has been no argument against the flag).